# What is the difference between making an array with {} and assigning values one by one in c

Tags: c, arrays, list

i am new to c and i am trying to sort an array values in a ascending order and i noticed a difference in my program when i do :

```
int t[5] = {5 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 1 };
```

and when i do :

```
int t[5];

t[0] = 5;
t[1] = 4;
t[2] = 3;
t[3] = 2;
t[4] = 1;
```

what is the difference ?

EDIT:
THE DIFFERENCE :

first program :

```
int t[5] = {5,4,3,2,1} ;

int i,aux;

for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    if(t[i] > t[i+1])
        aux=t[i];
        t[i]=t[i+1];
        t[i+1]=aux;

for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    printf("Val : %d\n" ,t[i] );
```

the output of the first program :

```
Val : 5
Val : 4
Val : 3
Val : 2
Val : 1
```

the second program :

```
int t[5] ;
t[0] = 5;
t[1] = 4;
t[2] = 3;
t[3] = 4;
t[4] = 5;
int i,aux;

for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    if(t[i] > t[i+1])
        aux=t[i];
        t[i]=t[i+1];
        t[i+1]=aux;

for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    printf("Val : %d\n" ,t[i] );
```

the second program output :

```
Val : 5
Val : 4
Val : 3
Val : 4
Val : 5
```

Comment: `and i noticed a difference in my program` what would that be?

Comment: Oh, I see, they will indeed be different, 'cuz you used different set of values.

Comment: When you initialize the array, at no point in time there is garbage anywhere (for multi-thread programs, ...). `int a[5] = {3, 2}; /*no garbage, even for a[4]*/` versus `int a[5]; /*garbage*/ a[0]; a[0] = 3; /*garbage*/ a[1];`. For a toy snippet, there really is not much of a difference, though when possible, it's a good programming technique to initialize.

Comment: @pmg but i did int t[5] in both

Comment: The difference is that one uses initialization and the other uses five assignments. Honestly, there's no important difference here. Both the snippets will get compiled to the same thing anyway.

Comment: @pmg If the array is static, then it will never have garbage values even if uninitialized.  If it's automatic, then the initializer list is handled dynamically.  Between the time the declaring block is entered and the time the intialization is complete, there will be garbage values in the array.

Comment: i edited the question and put the difference

Comment: @OussemaNehdi Your programs have undefined behavior.  Your array `t` has 5 elements.  The valid indices are 0 through 4, inclusive.  But what happens when `i` is 4 in your loop?  You are comparing `t[4]` with `t[5]`, even though `t[5]` lies beyond the end of the array.  Even worse, you're *changing* `t[5]`.  It's a severe bug in your code.  It's not surprising that you get different results.  The value past the end of `t` may be different in the two versions, and if you change it, anything can happen.  Fix the bugs.  Then the two versions should behave the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> for(i=0;i<5;i++)
>     if(t[i] > t[i+1])
>         aux=t[i];
>         t[i]=t[i+1];
>         t[i+1]=aux;
> ```

First: indentation does not reflect code structure. The `for` and `if` only affect 1 other statement

Your program is equivalent to

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (t[i] > t[i+1]) {
        aux = t[i];
    }
}
t[i] = t[i + 1];
t[i + 1] = aux;
```

Second: you are trying to access `t[5]` which does not exist, causing **Undefined Behaviour**.

Answer (score -1):

The first is called *initialization* and is performed at compile time (or the compiler generates the instructions to initialize the array).

The second is called *assignment* and is always performed at run-time.

Note: initializing a static array is performed completely at compile time. Initializing an automatic array (on the stack) is performed every time the function is entered, and the compiler has generated instructions for this.